# C#: how to have small box on WinForms ReportViewer report template?

Tags: winforms, reportviewer

I am using the Winforms ReportViewer in VS2005 to show a report which needs to have two small boxes that can be ticked with a pen when the report is printed.

How would I do this?  Would I use a font that has symbols such as a small boxes?  Will the font that I use need to be installed on each user's machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the characters in the WingDings2 font provides a small box for this purpose.